# Created Rmarkdown template, can't use it; namespace issue?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I've created an R package for an R markdown template, and am unable to knit to latex using the template.

I can install the package and create an R markdown file from my skeleton, and thought that the way to produce output using the template is a matter of specifying `output: mypackage::mytemplate` in the yaml header in the Rmd file. However, that leads to an error:

```
Error: 'mytemplate' is not an exported object from 'namespace:mypackage'
Execution halted
```

The template isn't in the namespace file for the package, but that appears to be generated by roxgyen, which I know nothing about.

I am happy to edit this question to provide additional details if they'd be useful.